# Summing the products of unique adjacent pairs in a 2D array

Tags: r

The first part of my code generates a 20 x 20 matrix randomly filled with 1 and -1 elements. As far as I can tell this part is working perfectly.

What I want to do next is to find the product of all unique neighboring element pairs and sum them together. Then this number should be multiplied by 'D' to give a final value. In theory the result should be somewhere between 0 and 800D.

What I have so far is a function that first creates a new 22 x 22 matrix, which is the original matrix with first row repeated as row 22, and row 20 also becoming the new row 1. The same thing is done with columns 1 and 20.

The idea there was that the data from column 20 of the original matrix would then be adjacent to the data from column 1, so every element from the original matrix would have 4 neighbors.

```
n <- 20

spin <- sample(c(-1, 1), n^2, replace = TRUE)

S <- array(spin, dim = c(n, n))

energy <- function(S, D = 1){

S1 <- S

S1 <- rbind(S[n,], S1, S[1,])

S1 <- cbind(S1[,n], S1, S1[,1])
```

Next I'm trying to find the neighbor products for each of the elements of the original matrix, add them together, and multiply by D. (i = 2 to i = 21, and j = 2 to j = 21 are the elements of the original matrix)

```
  for(i in 2:(n+1)) {
    for(j in 2:(n+1)) {
      E <- D * (sum((S1[i, j] * S1[(i-1), j]), (S1[i, j] * S1[i, (j-1)]),  
             (S1[i, j] * S1[i, (j+1)]), (S1[i, j] * S1[(i+1), j])))
}
}
return(E)
}

energy(S)
```

What I get out is a value between -4 and 4, so I assume that the neighbor products are only being found for one element, rather than each element in turn and then the results for each element being added together. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

In addition, if this code did work, it would count each neighboring pair twice. (i.e it would find a x b and b x a). Could I just divide the final result by 2 to find the value for only unique neighbor pairs?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to add to the previous sum : `E <- E + D (sum...*`

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!